# The column "name" has different values and I want to show these values in two different columns. but How?

Tags: sql, oracle

how to show result of "name" in two different columns i,e. it has 2 different values?? from first query I got Admin in name field, while from 2nd Query I got Mobile_user in name field, my desired result will be showing admin and mobile_user in two different fields

```
SELECT           T1.autgro_id id,
                 T1.name,
                 T2.use_id
FROM             adm_auth_groups_wv T1
                 INNER JOIN adm_user_auth_groups_wv T2
                 ON T1.autgro_id=T2.autgro_id
                 INNER JOIN ym_customers_wv T3
                 ON T1.cus_id=T3.cus_id
WHERE            T3.cus_id_parent = 4
                 AND T2.use_id  =24

UNION All

SELECT           T1.autgro_id id,
                 T1.name,
                 T2.use_id
FROM             adm_auth_groups_wv T1
                 INNER JOIN adm_user_auth_groups_wv T2
                 ON T1.autgro_id = T2.autgro_id
WHERE            yard_functions_pkg.get_parent_from_cus_id(T1.cus_id) = 4 AND
                 T1.autgro_id
                 NOT IN           
                 (SELECT 
                 T2.autgro_id
                 FROM  
                 adm_user_auth_groups_wv T2
                 WHERE
                 T2.use_id=24)
```

Comment: Two different values are comma seperated or atomic??

Comment: can you show us sample data, so we can see how the name field is stored ?

Comment: Atomic values @AnkitBajpai

Comment: @AymanBarhoum name field cantailns names like "Admin", Mobile_user"

Comment: use join rather than union.

Comment: But how to show 'name' field's values in two different fields. @Amee

Comment: I guess you are looking for an **INLINE VIEW**.

Comment: Can you edit your question with sample data and what would be the desired result from it?

Comment: sorry @JorgeCampos Can't post image of sample data due to less reputation on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dummy column in both queries, populate one column in the first query and the other in the second.

```
SELECT           T1.autgro_id id,
                 T1.name admin_user,
                 null mobile_user,
                 T2.use_id
FROM             adm_auth_groups_wv T1
                 INNER JOIN adm_user_auth_groups_wv T2
                 ON T1.autgro_id=T2.autgro_id
                 INNER JOIN ym_customers_wv T3
                 ON T1.cus_id=T3.cus_id
WHERE            T3.cus_id_parent = 4
                 AND T2.use_id  =24
UNION All
SELECT           T1.autgro_id id,
                 null admin_user,
                 T1.name mobile_user,
                 T2.use_id
FROM             adm_auth_groups_wv T1
                 INNER JOIN adm_user_auth_groups_wv T2
                 ON T1.autgro_id = T2.autgro_id
WHERE            yard_functions_pkg.get_parent_from_cus_id(T1.cus_id) = 4 AND
                 T1.autgro_id
                 NOT IN           
                 (SELECT 
                 T2.autgro_id
                 FROM  
                 adm_user_auth_groups_wv T2
                 WHERE
                 T2.use_id=24)
```

Comment: @Ahmad You're welcome. Please be so kind to accept my answer by clicking the grey checkmark on the left of the answer.